# Order mysql query in the same order I provide the OR statements in

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's a query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
 WHERE id = 1
    OR id = 100
    OR id = 50
```

Note that I provided the ids in this order: 1,100,50.

I want the rows to come back in that order:  1,100,50.

Currently, i comes back 1,50,100 - basically in ascending order.  Assume the rows in the table were inserted in ascending order also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this with `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY
   id = 1 DESC, id = 100 DESC, id = 50 DESC
```

`0` is before `1` in `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I did not know I could do this, it's exactly what I needed.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the MySQL specific [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
  SELECT t.* 
    FROM table t
   WHERE t.id IN (1, 100, 50)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(CAST(t.id AS VARCHAR(8)), '1,100,50')
```

Comment: You better hope this is a tiny table or you can forget about getting any kind of performance out of it. This is *temporary table* territory in the worst possible way.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to approach this would put the list in a subquery:

```
select table.*
from table join
     (select 1 as id, 1 as ordering union all
      select 100 as id, 2 as ordering union all
      select 50 as id, 3 as ordering
     ) list
     on table.id = list.id
order by list.ordering
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM new
WHERE ID =1
OR ID =100
OR ID =50
ORDER BY ID=1 DESC,ID=100 DESC,ID=50 DESC ;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/796e2/5

Answer (score 0):

... WHERE id IN (x,y,x) ORDER BY FIELD (id,x,y,z)